# Qual a relação entre OAuth e Rest?

Tags: rest, restful, oauth2

boa noite.

Gostaria de utilizar a API de um determinado site (Mercado Pago para ser específico) para construir uma aplicação. Estudando um pouco de sua documentação vi que a API deles é baseada em Rest e utilizam o OAuth, embora saiba que essa é uma matéria futura em minha faculdade gostaria desde já começar a aprender, mas confesso que fiquei meio perdido no assunto.

Poderiam me explicar qual é a relação do OAuth com o Rest/Restful? Poderiam também finalizar dando dicas do que devo estudar para construir esse tipo de aplicação?

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest não tem relação direta com OAuth, o primeiro é uma arquitetura de troca de informação, e o segundo é um mecanismo de autorização (na verdade, [acaba sendo confundido com autenticação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67981/70), mas isso vale um "debate" separado).

Poderiam muito bem ter usado OAuth pra você se autenticar em um serviço que não usa REST, e a recíproca é verdadeira.

Um exemplo disso é o uso do SMTP do Google para "aplicações mais seguras", que usa uma variante chamada XOAuth2, ou seja, uma autenticação nova para um protocolo "antigo".

Só pra comparar (exagerando um pouco), sua pergunta seria "Qual a relação do meu cadeado Pado com o portão da minha casa?" - Você poderia ter usado outras marcas de cadeado para o portão, ou poderia ter usado este mesmo cadeado num armário, em vez do portão. A relação entre as duas coisas é mera escolha de quem disponibilizou.

Uma dica ao usar e estudar OAuth, é entender que OAuth e OAuth2 tem diferenças significativas, e você deve focar na documentação correta, e se referir sempre usando o nome correto de uma e de outra. Atualmente o que se usa comumente é o OAuth2.

Sobre REST:
[O que é REST e RESTful?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783)

Em inglês, na Wikipedia:
[OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, esclareceu bem minhas dúvidas.